# mysql5.58 unstart server in mac os 10.6.5

Tags: mysql, macos

MySQL 5.5.8 uninstall MAC OS 10.6.5,restart computer is message “/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM” has not been started because it does not have the proper security settings. i set 
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server

Locate the configuration defining the basedir and set the following : 
basedir=/usr/local/mysql 
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data

bug i click the mysql preference start mysql server isn't start

and i sudo chown -R root:wheel /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM and restart again ,not warning message but mysql server not start ,why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just installed MySQL 5.5.8 (mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg) on Mac os X 10.6.5 and also had the problem that MySQL was not starting.

After reading this post:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,399397,399606#msg-399606

> Modify the mysql.server script file
>   using the following command :
>
> ```
> sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server
> ```
>
> Locate the configuration defining the
>   basedir and set the following:
>
> ```
> basedir=/usr/local/mysql 
> datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
> ```
>
> Save the file and start the mysql
>   server in the system preferences /
>   terminal

This solved the problem.

Hope this helps. Thanks to http://forums.mysql.com/profile.php?11,3773555 !

Answer (score 1):

cheers!
above answer worked for me. now i can start and stop my mysql from system preferences.
The great thing about this solution is that it fixed my problem with mysql i had before 
the problem on my  mac os x 10.6.5 was: even after unsuccessful attempt to start mysql by its preference pane i was starting mysql in terminal by 
"sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start" command; after trying to connect to my server by /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql command in terminal i was getting "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'" error.
i know it's unrelated but for reference my computer is 64bit mac with mac os x 10.6.5, installed  mysql-5.5.8-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg on it.

Answer (score 1):

You guys are the best.
It worked for me (controlling mysql from the system preferences.

Unfortunately, I also had to include the user in the wheel group:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a "user-id" -t "user-id" wheel

"user-id"@"machine-id": Sun Jan 30 14:22:45 /Library/StartupItems
$ tree -Dpugas
.
`-- [drwxr-xr-x root     wheel            136 Dec  3 13:58]  MySQLCOM
    |-- [-rwxr-xr-x root     wheel           1300 Dec  3 13:58]  MySQLCOM
    `-- [-rw-r--r-- root     wheel            469 Dec  3 13:58]  StartupParameters.plist

1 directory, 2 files
```