# Create MySQL database in OS X Lion

Tags: mysql, macos

I am trying to set up a dev environment on my Mac laptop, and I have run into some trouble when installing mysql. When I try to create a database, I get the following error:

> ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'SummerGypsy_development'
>   (errno: 2

From what I have gathered, this means there was some problem in creating the database on the disc.

Here is how I installed mysql:

First, using Homebrew, I executed:

> brew install mysql

Once that finished, I tried running mysql_install_db, but got an error. To remedy this error, I ended up running

> mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local/

I can run mysql, but creating a database does not work. I ran

> mysqladmin variables | grep datadir

To find where mysql was trying to create the database. The output was: /usr/local/mysql/data

/usr/local/mysql and /usr/local/mysql/data directories do not actually exist, and I have a feeling that the datadir is pointing here because of the basedir I passed into mysql_install_db. As a quick fix, I tried creating both directories, and then running

> chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql

to give mysql permissions in this directory. This did not fix the problem, though.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try installing from the .dmg file (installer, system preferences pane, and startup script) that is distributed directly from MySQL.  There is a thread on [Getting MySQL work on OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317614/getting-mysql-work-on-osx-10-7-lion) that you might want to take a look at.  These steps helped me get MySQL running on OSX Lion.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

you need to change the permissions in the data.

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried lot of the suggestions including the file permission reset with no luck. But i then restarted the mysql using the command "./mysqld_safe &" (excluding quotes) and it worked.