# Install MySQLdb on snow leopard without XCode

Tags: python, mysql, macos

Is it possible to install the MySQLdb python module on Snow Leopard without XCode?

I am not a member of the $99/year developer programs, so I do not have XCode.

Comment: see here :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317614/getting-mysql-work-on-osx-10-7-lion

Comment: or use the binaries provided by mysql itself. www.mysql.com

Comment: @Tronic I meant the python module. I've got mysql running. I've edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: @jterrace From what I saw on their website, it's free only if you are a member of one of the developer programs. Is that not right?

Comment: You should install Xcode regardless of how you install MySQLdb.  You will likely need a C compiler at some point for other third-party Python packages that include C extension modules.  You can download Xcode 3 for Snow Leopard after free registration at http://developer.apple.com/resources/

Comment: @ben-noland no, only an apple ID is required. Xcode is free.

Answer (score 1):

XCode 4.2 is a free download from the App Store (which you have if you've upgraded to latest Snow Leopard versions)
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12

I think on SL they may charge you something like $4 for it, but there is really no way around this as you need the whole compiler+libs stack that is provided with XCode