# How to start MySQL server from command line on Mac OS Lion?

Tags: mysql, macos, command-line, osx-lion

I installed mySQL on my Mac. Beside starting the SQL server with mySQL.prefPane tool installed in System Preferences, I want to know the instructions to start from command-line.
I do as follows:

After

> su root

I start the mySQL server by command-line, but it produces an error as below:

> **sh-3.2#** /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld
>
> **111028 16:57:43** [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because
> file system for /usr/local/mysql-5.5.17-osx10.6-x86_64/data/ is case
> insensitive
>
> **111028 16:57:43** [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of
> the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
>
> **111028 16:57:43** [ERROR] Aborting
>
> **111028 16:57:43** [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

Comment: On macOS, use `mdfind mysql.server` to see where your server executable is

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Try  `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`

Example:

```
shell> sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
(Enter your password, if necessary)
(Press Control-Z)
shell> bg
(Press Control-D or enter "exit" to exit the shell)
```

You can also add these to your bash startup scripts:

```
export MYSQL_HOME=/usr/local/mysql
alias start_mysql='sudo $MYSQL_HOME/bin/mysqld_safe &'
alias stop_mysql='sudo $MYSQL_HOME/bin/mysqladmin shutdown'
```

Comment: It works. But I can't exit the pointer from the performing of the command. How to stop it when the Terminal window is in performing.

Comment: Note that this answer does not apply if you installed mysql with Homebrew.

Comment: For me it ended up being just "mysqld <action>", the file is located at /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld

Answer (score 405):

Simply:

`mysql.server start`

`mysql.server stop`

`mysql.server restart`

Comment: this is what I got for this one: `. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/XXXX.pid).`

Comment: @nyxee You may need to run it with `sudo`!

Comment: I got the same error even with `sudo`.  On mac Big Sur and MySQL 5.7, I needed to stop/start with: `sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` and 
`sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`

Comment: Using only "mysql.server start" didn't worked for me. So figured it out merging @BenjaminCrouzier commentary. Like so:

I'm using macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra:

1. Use mdfind mysql.server to see where executable files are.

2. Add Alias to my bash file (.zshrc in my case) 
export MYSQL_SERVER=/usr/local/mysql-8.0.12-macos10.13-x86_64/support-files/
alias mysql.start="sudo $MYSQL_SERVER/mysql.server start"
alias mysql.stop="sudo $MYSQL_SERVER//mysql.server stop"
alias mysql.restart="sudo $MYSQL_SERVER/mysql.server restart"

3. Source the bash: source ~/.zshrc 

Done!

Answer (score 151):

I like the aliases too ... however, I've had issues with MySQLCOM for start ... it fails silently ... My workaround is akin to the others ... ~/.bash_aliases

```
alias mysqlstart='sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start'
alias mysqlstop='sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop'
```

Comment: Other answers failed on OSX 10.7.5 w/ latest MySQL install.  This one did the trick - thanks!

Comment: Thanks!! I wanted to start mysql and be able to close the terminal as well and this worked. What is the difference between this way of starting it and the mysqld_safe way?

Comment: From [mysqld_safe vs mysql.server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/automatic-start.html)

Before mysql.server starts the server, it changes location to the MySQL installation directory, and then invokes mysqld_safe.

Comment: I did try the command, but it couldn't start, and it seems to be I can't have a pid file. What should I do?

Comment: @ray6080 , I think you forgot to type `sudo` in front of `./mysql.server start`. From the **support_files** directory, the following command works for me. `sudo ./mysql.server start`

Comment: @AustinA wow! I know its an older comment, but thank you! this worked for me (MySQL 8.0.31, MacOS version 12.6.3)

Answer (score 99):

As [this](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/start-stop-mysql-from-the-command-line-terminal-osx-linux/) helpful article states:
On OS X to start/stop MySQL from the command line:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start 
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

On Linux start/stop from the command line:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start 
/etc/init.d/mysqld stop 
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Some Linux flavours offer the service command too

```
# service mysqld start 
# service mysqld stop 
# service mysqld restart
```

or

```
 # service mysql start 
 # service mysql stop 
 # service mysql restart
```

Comment: no such file or directory from `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop `

Answer (score 83):

If you installed it with homebrew, the binary will be somewhere like

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/bin/mysqld
```

which means you can start it with

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/support-files/mysql.server start
```

and stop it with

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

---

Edit: As Jacob Raccuia mentioned, make sure you put the appropriate version of MySQL in the path.

Comment: yeah!!!!!! i didn't realize i installed it this way! make sure you put the appropriate version of mysql in the path

Answer (score 50):

Maybe your mysql-server didn't start.

You can try

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql.server start
```

Comment: This works on Mac OSX Big Sur as of January 9, 2022!

Answer (score 32):

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
```

make alias in .bash_profile

```
alias start_mysql="/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start"
alias stop_mysql="/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop"
```

and if you are trying to run as root use following safe mode

```
sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
```

if you are still having issues starting, a recommended read:
[mysql5.58 unstart server in mac os 10.6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486543/mysql5-58-unstart-server-in-mac-os-10-6-5/4498370#4498370)

Answer (score 14):

For me this solution worked on mac Sierra OS:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
SUCCESS!
```

Comment: For me, the path was `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server`

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.29/bin/mysql.server for me. Just depends how you install it. Obviously Cellar is Brew on MacOS

Answer (score 13):

My MySQL is installed via homebrew on OS X ElCaptain. What fixed it was running

`brew doctor`

- which suggested that I run

`sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`

Then:

```
brew update
mysql.server start
```

mysql is now running

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted. This happened to me during a brew update. Running brew doctor, and then following the instructions to add a particular path to my bash profile fixed the issues. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

If it's installed with homebrew try just typing down `mysql.server` in terminal and that should be it.
AFAIK it executable will be under /usr/local/bin/mysql.server.

If not you can always run following "locate mysql.server" which will tell you where to find such file.

Answer (score 6):

If you have MySQL installed through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) these commands will help you:

```
# For starting
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

# For stoping
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Comment: The LauchAgent for mysql wasn't there by default. Running `brew info mysql` (which I learned from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4622474/459863) stated that I first had to run `ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents`. After that, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

MySql server startup error 'The server quit without updating PID file '

if you have installed mysql from homebrew

close mysql server from preferences of mac

```
ps ax | grep mysql

#kill all the mysql process running
sudo kill -9 pid

which mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql
Admins-MacBook-Pro:bin username$ sudo mysql.server start

Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS! 

Admins-MacBook-Pro:bin username$ which mysql

/usr/local/bin/mysql

Admins-MacBook-Pro:bin username$ ps ax | grep mysql

54916 s005  S      0:00.02 /bin/sh 
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.27_1/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/Admins-MacBook-Pro.local.pid
55012 s005  S      0:00.40 /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.27_1/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.27_1 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.27_1/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=Admins-MacBook-Pro.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/Admins-MacBook-Pro.local.pid
55081 s005  S+     0:00.00 grep mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

On mac Big Sur and MySQL 5.7, I needed to stop/start with:

`sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`

and

`sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`

This answer came from https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/start-stop-mysql-from-the-command-line-terminal-osx-linux/

Comment: working on macOS monterray for mysql 8.0.28

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had downloaded the mysql server and installed it but I didn't click on the run server that showed up on the last installer page.

In order to start my server manually in the terminal (without adding aliases), I used this in the terminal and it works.

Start Server:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Stop Server:

```
sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

More info at the link below:
https://www.databasestar.com/start-mysql-server/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (MacOs):

Start MySQL:

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`

Stop MySQL:

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`

Comment: This is working. Mac OS Sonoma 14.3.1 and MySQL 8.3 for ARM64

Answer (score 0):

```
111028 16:57:43 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
```

Have you set a root password for your mysql installation? This is different to your sudo root password. Try `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: When I ran the above line, it produce: 

Can't find a 'mysql' client in PATH or ./bin