# mysql restart does not work

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with restarting mysql server. It used to restart when I run it with mysqld restart, but I don't know what happened now, it just won't restart giving me an error: you have an error in your sql syntax. I tried different restart methods:

```
mysql restart
mysqld restart
sudo restart mysql
service mysqld restart
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

and getting the same error. How do I restart it?

Comment: `service mysqld restart` what's your OS?

Comment: tried that one as well, mac os x

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927854/start-mysql-server-from-command-line-on-mac-os-lion

Comment: mysqld_safe Fatal error: Can't remove the pid file:Please remove it manually and start /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe again;
mysqld daemon not started. What is a pid file? should I remove it?

Comment: It is better to do mysql stop and then mysql start. You tried that ?

Comment: I need mysqld restart. It worked before. Maybe the problem now is something to do with the fact that I installed homebrew package and it affected somehow my server

Comment: Sorry, see the edit. i need you to shell> mysql.server stop
shell> mysql.server start