# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

when i run my code, i get this exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:357)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2482)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2519)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2304)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:367)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:517)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Aug 25, 2015 8:23:45 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SCHWERWIEGEND: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:457)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.create(Unknown Source)
```

I don't know where is the problem. But yesterday i worked fine.

my database.properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/streaming
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=password

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.showsql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

It is possible for me to run mysql directly from command line. Where is the problem? Was is wrong. 
I use spring 4 and hibernate with mysql as database language.

Has someone any ideas?

Thank.

Comment: check the DB server status. Is it working.

Comment: Do you use JPA.em("default") ?

Answer (score 9):

There is CommunicationsException: Communications link failure.

If you get a SQLException: Connection refused or Connection timed out or a MySQL specific

```
CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

then it means that the DB isn't reachable at all. This can have one or more of the following causes:

- IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong.
- Hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by local DNS server.
- Port number is missing or wrong in JDBC URL.
- DB server is down.
- DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
- DB server has run out of connections.
- Something in between Java and DB is blocking connections, e.g. a firewall or proxy.

To solve the one or the other, follow the following advices:

- Verify and test them with ping.
- Refresh DNS or use IP address in JDBC URL instead.
- Verify it based on my.cnf of MySQL DB.
- Start the DB.
- Verify if mysqld is started without the --skip-networking option.
- Restart the DB and fix your code accordingly that it closes connections in finally.
- Disable firewall and/or configure firewall/proxy to allow/forward the port.

Source: [More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database/2840358#2840358)

Comment: I am running a Spring Boot Microservice with MariaDB database, where I am facing the same issue. 
None of the above reasons hold true in my case. The service is able to connect to the db for a few hours and then I start seeing this connection error. When I restart the service, the issue is resolved again. It appears that the connection pool runs out of valid connections. I have played around with spring.datasource.tomcat.* properties (testOnBorrow:true, validateQuery: SELECT 1, testWhileIdle: true, timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1000, logAbandoned: true), but that has not helped.

Answer (score 2):

DB is down.
You must start the DB server and check connectivity with either telnet or mysql command line client first.

Comment: i can run succefully mysql -u root -p on the console. DB down. But when i run with sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
....................................................................................................  i get this: ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Me-MBP.local.pid).

Comment: what linux are you using. Try sudo service mysqld start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927854/start-mysql-server-from-command-line-on-mac-os-lion or this: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/start-stop-mysql-from-the-command-line-terminal-osx-linux/

Comment: can't think of anything but ps aux | grep mysqld then if exists, sudo kill -9 pid, check firewall, restart.

Comment: Thank but i don't time enough time. I decided to reinstall mysql and it is working fine now.

Comment: Strange, could be due to that pid file staling there

Comment: hummmm. When i start my mac and run the mysql server i get the same error. What is wrong?

Comment: how do you start mysql server?

Comment: yes, but same error, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234142/error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file-usr-local-mysql-data-mac-loca

Answer (score 2):

I see that @Amit Tamrakar have good answer but I want to add:

- if you make a lot of requests to db, (I mean connections), may be that application (some app thread) just wait for use free connection from app db connection pool, but throws timeout exception.

```
.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30005ms.

Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

You can try to increase db connection pool in application config file, for example:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
```

You can set size which you need. This config in app by `default` is `8`.
And we need remember that each db have own free db connection size which we don't need exceed.
I mean if db have 5 free connection and you want to use 10 connections in your app then we will receive so exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I was not unable to figure out the exact cause, but I realized that it was because of some thread pools since I was able to connect to the db using the terminal.
for checking the connectivity you can use the below command.

```
psql -h hostname -U username -d database
```

so restarting the server worked for me.