# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Mac.local.pid)

Tags: mysql, macos, shell, osx-yosemite

After install, run fine mysql and restart my mac, i get this error, when i call this command line:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

Hier the error:

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Mac.local.pid).
```

And when i try to connect me to `mysql -u root -p`, this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I try the solution in this link
[MySQL does not start when upgrading OSX to Yosemite or El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954230/mysql-does-not-start-in-osx-yosemite-10-10), but nothing. I also try to change the owner of the mysql folder with:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/mysql/
```

But nothing.

Any ideas?

Thank

Comment: try this and post the output

sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql server startup error 'The server quit without updating PID file '](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file)

Comment: [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.26) starting as process 7527 ...
 7527 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-5.6.26-osx10.8-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
 7527 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
7527 [ERROR] Aborting
7527 [Note] Binlog end
7527 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown

Comment: @BK435 i am not a mac profit. Where is the location of the error log? in my /var/log/ is no mysql.log file

Comment: there are nothing in this file

Answer (score 4):

start your mysql in safe_mode.its working for me. hope it would work also for you

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe start
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall mysql

```
brew uninstall mysql@5.7
```

and reinstall again

```
brew install mysql@5.7
```

When I check my terminal I could see this warning

```
 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
```

then I had to do this

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
```

and  open my.cnf like this

```
nano /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

and remove this line `mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

then do the post-install like this

```
brew postinstall mysql@5.7
```

Which finally worked. I had wasted a whole day on this. Hope someone finds this useful.