# Can't start MySQL Server from command line while at the same time keep the Preference pane functional

Tags: mysql

I'm running macOS Mojave, just installed MySQL using the official installer. I can start/stop the server without problem from the **Preference pane**.
But from the command line I always get **Permission denied** trouble:

```
$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
./usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 199: /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err: Permission denied
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid).
```

I also tried with the `mysqld` and `mysqld_safe` commands with the same results.

The **owner** of the **data directory** is the **_mysql** user:

```
$ ls -l mysql/
drwxr-x---  42 _mysql  _mysql    1344 Nov  5 21:14 data
```

I would do `su _mysql 'mysql.server start'` for example, but I don't know the password of `_mysql` if it has any, I think it's not a login account.

So how can I start the server **from the command line**?

### Update

As the official MySQL documentation explains [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/changing-mysql-user.html), to run the server as normal user you have to own the data directory recursively works:

```
$ chown bob -R /usr/local/mysql/data
```

I can start/stop the server from the **command line**, using any of the commands above, and connect to the server as well.

Problem is, now it doesn't work the **Preference pane**!
Now the question is: Is there any way of getting back the Pref pane working? Most importantly, why did that happen?

Comment: Don't change the owner of the mysql files to your user account. The configured mysql user (I guess it's the `_mysql` user) is the one who should run the mysql server, not your user account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [start MySQL server from command line on Mac OS Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927854/start-mysql-server-from-command-line-on-mac-os-lion)

Comment: @Progman, in that post they reference the official MySQL docs, and there they changed ownership of the data dir. Check it out:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/changing-mysql-user.html

Answer (score 0):

`mysqld_safe` is just a wrapper for the `mysqld` command that will start for you your mysql server with the correct user.

However, you should have to run it with `sudo`. If you find or manage to replace the password for your **mysql** user, you might be able to use directly the `mysqld` command.

So, a quick way to start your server is: `sudo mysqld_safe`.

Further details can be found on [MySQL documentation: Starting the server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/starting-server.html)

Comment: I know `mysqld_safe` is a wrapper for `mysqld`. Nope, I don't need to use sudo to start the server using any of those commands.

Answer (score 0):

So no, the solution can't be found in [start MySQL server from command line on Mac OS Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927854/start-mysql-server-from-command-line-on-mac-os-lion), but it can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255671/error-mysql-server-pid-file-could-not-be-found)
Basically in that post they explain that the **pid file** used by the **launchd service** (the **pref pane** uses that service)  has a different name of the one that `msqld` uses:

- The **Preference pane** call it `mysqld.local.pid`
- `msqld` calls it `the_name_of_your_localhost.local.pid`

So if you start the server from the pane you mess the name of the pid file, and then the commands get confused because it looks for a pid file named differently. And the other way around.

We can find the same naming trouble with the **error log file**.

Also I found out that the names for the **socket files** are also different:

- `/tmp/mysql.sock` for the commands
- `/tmp/mysqlx.sock` for the service/pane

Maybe there's a way using configuration files to use unified names, but I couldn't make it work. At least now I understand the problem, although don't know how to fix it. In the meantime I'll have to to choose: either the **command line** or the **preference pane**, but not both. They are **incompatible** ;-)