# Wordpress mysql service error ERROR: Failed to start "mysql": cannot start service: Process exited with status 3

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bitnami

I'm hoping someone can help me, i've been working on a website using wordpress for the past 3 months on my mac, only when i tried to access it this past weekend the mysql service won't run and i keep getting the error

```
ERROR: Failed to start "mysql": cannot start service: Process exited with status 3
```

Can anyone help me get my site up and running again?

This is the first tie using Wordpress so i'm not really sure what I'm doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

i've managed to run mysql in safe mode and this is the code it gives

```
Last login: Mon Jul 13 22:23:09 on ttys001
Lukes-iMac:~ lukejackson$/Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe ; exit;
/Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/my_print_defaults: line 12: /Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/my_print_defaults.bin: cannot execute binary file
/Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/my_print_defaults: line 12: /Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/my_print_defaults.bin: Undefined error: 0
/Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/my_print_defaults: line 12: /Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/my_print_defaults.bin: cannot execute binary file
/Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/my_print_defaults: line 12: /Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/my_print_defaults.bin: Undefined error: 0
/Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 674: /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/Lukes-iMac.err: No such file or directory
Logging to '/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/Lukes-iMac.err'.2020-07-13T21:43:10.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/Lukes-iMac.err: No such file or directory
/Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 199: /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/Lukes-iMac.err: No such file or directory
/Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 937: /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/Lukes-iMac.err: No such file or directory
2020-07-13T21:43:10.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/Lukes-iMac.pid ended
/Users/lukejackson/.bitnami/stackman/machines/wordpress/volumes/root/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/Lukes-iMac.err: No such file or directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Did you try restarting the MySQL service? Or maybe just restarting the computer.

Comment: Hi @DavideCasiraghi, yep that was my first and only thought to resolving the problem, unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Maybe the disk is full where the MySQL database is located?

Comment: @Damocles to be honest i'm not 100% sure, i installed wordpress on my mac. when i run my site the url in the address bar is that similar to an ip address.

Comment: @BBLJ84 This most likely means the MySQL server is also installed on your Mac. Therefore, if your local harddisk is not full and you can still save stuff on it, that wasn't the problem apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Your local database server is failing to start up, and it's being started with enough layers between you and it that any reporting it's doing on why is being hidden.  To attempt to start it while being able to see what it's complaining about, try the methodology here: [start MySQL server from command line on Mac OS Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927854/start-mysql-server-from-command-line-on-mac-os-lion)

Comment: hi @chaos, thanks for your reply, sadly most if not all of the commands on that thread lead to a "command not found" message being returned. not sure if im typing it in correctly tho?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here.

Thank you for using our solution. Please note that the OS X VM solution is a VM we build and configure with the application. You need to open the Console of the VM when running any command, can you try to open the console and run the start command?

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

You can use the ctlscript.sh file to stop the services and get the status as well. If the database can't be started, you can take a look at the database's log file (/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log) to get more information

```
sudo tail -n 30 /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log
```