# Is MySQL safe mode the default mode?

Tags: mysql, macos, default, mode

I just upgraded my Mac from Leopard to Snow Leopard and in the process my web development environment broke. I have managed to fix a weird "[bug](http://www.perkiset.org/forum/all_things_apple/apache_osx_and_ulimit_a_little_chunk_of_weirdness-t909.0.html)" in Apache that didn't happen before and I have restored my httpd-vhosts.conf file, and I have also got MySQL running again thanks to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334272/cant-start-mysql-in-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard#3263280).

Now I notice that MySQL is running in safe mode, though, and my question is, if that's the default mode? Specifically, I want to know whether that is the mode MySQL was running in before (and if it's the default, I would assume that it was) or if upgrading to Snow Leopard changed something that causes MySQL to not not start in safe mode anymore (assuming that it was not starting in safe mode before).

Note, MySQL starts automatically on startup for me, and after stopping it and starting it again from the System Preferences panel, MySQL still runs in safe mode. (Just noting this to clarify that I am not manually starting MySQL in safe mode.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "safe mode" you mean the MySQL wrapper?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqld-safe.html

If so, then yeah, it's the standard/default mechanism for startup.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me if this wrapper is usually also used for production environments?

Comment: From all that I have experienced, yes.

Comment: No prob. Don't forget to upvote the answer or mark it as correct if you see fit. :)