# MySQL pid ended (cannot start mysql)

Tags: mysql, database, macos, mysql-error-1064

I have a clean install of MySQL (mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64).  I am on Lion (OS 10.7.4) with a Mac Pro Quad Core. I installed MySQL the GUI installer and also installed the pref pane and the startup item.

However when I run:

```
sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
```

I get this message:

```
120515 17:58:19 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/data/Dannys-Mac-Pro.local.err'.
120515 17:58:19 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/data
120515 17:58:20 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/data/Dannys-Mac-Pro.local.pid ended
```

I also cannot start MySQL from the preference pane.

Here is what I have tried so far based on the hours of Googling and research today:

**Permissions issues?**

[This:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9643282/819276)

```
cd /usr/local
sudo chown mysql mysql
sudo chown mysql mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64
sudo chown _mysql mysql
sudo chown _mysql mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64
```

and

```
sudo chown -R /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/
sudo chown -R /usr/local/mysql
```

[This:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5124022/819276)

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
```

**Link issues?**

[This:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4755143/819276)

in /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server -- I did:

```
basedir="/usr/local/mysql"
datadir="/usr/local/mysql/data"
```

> In the file /etc/rc.common add the follow line at end:
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &

[This:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3263280/819276)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64 /usr/local/mysql
```

I also tried the [removal process here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2685337/819276) and reinstalled but this did not seem to make a difference. I also launched Activity Monitor in OS X to see if any other mySQL processes were running by chance but they were not.

Nothing above worked so I am sort of at wits end. Here is the log from the .err file located at:

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/data/Dannys-Mac-Pro.local.err

120515 18:07:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/data/Dannys-Mac-Pro.local.pid ended
120515 18:13:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/data
120515 18:13:01 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
120515 18:13:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120515 18:13:01 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120515 18:13:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120515 18:13:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120515 18:13:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120515 18:13:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120515 18:13:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120515 18:13:01 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120515 18:13:01  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120515 18:13:02 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120515 18:13:02 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
120515 18:13:02 [ERROR] Aborting

120515 18:13:02  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120515 18:13:03  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
120515 18:13:03 [Note] /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

120515 18:13:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/data/Dannys-Mac-Pro.local.pid ended
```

**Update:** I upgraded the same machine from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion 10.8.1 and MySQL works perfectly fine now with the upgrade, I had to do nothing extra.

Comment: `[ERROR] /usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'` - does `/usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/my.cnf` contain anything like `skip-locking`? If not, does `bin/mysqld_safe` (which is just a shell script)? If yes, remove it and try again.

Comment: @DannyEnglander I've had this issue for 2 days now - how did you deal with it?

Comment: @sscirrus unfortunately, I had to revert back to OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard and that solved the issue. I was extremely disappointed that I could not get this working on Lion. Probably one of the most frustrating things I've ever gone through...

Comment: @DannyEnglander I very much hope that someone will find a solution to this. I had this problem on Snow Leopard and the only way I resolved it last night was to Time Machine my computer back 2 weeks. Very frustrating here also.

Comment: Update: I upgraded the same machine from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion 10.8.1 and MySQL works perfectly fine now with the upgrade, I had to do nothing extra.

Answer (score 11):

I have the same problem when installing mysql newest version mysql-5.6.10-osx10.7-x86.dmg for my MAC OS 10.7.5. Following is my solutions.
First , delete the mysql installed

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
```

Then, get [mysql-5.1.68-osx10.6-x86.dmg](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html) , install this old version, and done!

Comment: If you want to keep your databases, then you should backup /usr/local/mysql/data/ first!

Comment: Backing up the databases is a good idea. 

By the way, just overwriting the "data" folder in the new installation with the old one did not work for me, but copying the actual databases sub-folders within the old "data" folder to the new one did.

Answer (score 10):

As @AndPy says, the same with me, if you `ls -l` the `/usr/local/var/mysql` you can see that the file `COMPUTER-NAME.local.err` is owned by `_mysql` or some such.... in this case just erase the file and `mysql.server start` will create new one owned by your user and will start properly this time :)

If the file is already owned by your user, this wont help, you got to google more :(

Answer (score 6):

I found this error on redmine bitnami stack because owner of files in directory data incorrect.

Check owner of directory /mysql/data/ must be 'mysql' user

Hope this help.

Comment: Bingo. If you're on bitnami lamp stack, chown mysql opt/bitnami/mysql/data -R (you must be logged in as root). Then start mysql with $ cd /opt/bitnami
$ sudo ./ctlscript.sh restart mysql

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem after updating to OS X Mavericks.

> Starting MySQL . ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Like [Redrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980430/redrick) and [AndPy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1298277/andpy) mentioned I also had to rename (actually I deleted the file) the error file located in `$ cd /usr/local/var/mysql`. My error file was called `localhost.err`. After removing the file with `$ rm localhost.err` I could finally start MySQL again with `$ mysql.server start`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

In /usr/local/var/mysql I found a file in the form COMPUTER-NAME.local.err. Simply changing that file name solved the problem. I could now start the mysql server with

> mysql.server start

Answer (score 3):

My answer is very similar to others, but slightly different and this applies mostly to a bitnami mamp stack. The fix for me was:

`sudo chown -R mysql mysql/`

The `mysql/` directory is the one located in `Applications/<mampstack-version>/`

The above sets the mysql to be the owner of the mysql directory recursively into the other directories.

Comment: On my Linux mint, I had to do two things:

`sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld`

and

`sudo chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to absolutely get this thing working do the following:

You need to uninstall mysql first so do that, before you do this though, make sure you have a backup of all your DBs.

`brew remove mysql`

Then you need to make sure certain files are uninstalled, make a batch script of the following commands and run it:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

Go to `/etc/hostconfig` using your favorite editing program and remove the line `MYSQLCOM=-YES-`

Then run `brew cleanup` then install mysql using `brew install mysql`

After you've done this you'll probably get the same error again. Head over to the folder `cd /usr/local/var/mysql/`. There should be a file in there called `localhost.local.err`

run `cat ./localhost.local.err` and look in the file. You should see something similar to:

`2018-03-24 15:41:49 140735679804288 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 48: Address already in use`

`2018-03-24 15:41:49 140735679804288 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?`

If you do, run the command `sudo lsof -i :3306` and you'll probably get something back like this:

`COMMAND PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld   74 _mysql   20u  IPv6 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXX      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)`

This means mysql is already running and listening on port 3306 and you need to kill it. Use `top` to kill the program or just use Activity Monitor to kill it. Either way once that's done go back to `cd /usr/local/var/mysql/` and delete the folder `localhost.local.err`.

Once that's done run mysql.server start and you should get the following:

`180324 15:46:18 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
 SUCCESS!`

And congrats. I've been trying to fix this for a week and it's such an easy fix and I just figured it out. I hate myself.

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql` I have all my databases in this directory, which I don't want to erase…

Comment: @pilat just take a backup. This worked perfectly on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: @AhmedHashem yup yup. That was actually the first instruction I gave in the post.

Answer (score 0):

120515 18:13:01 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

- Regarding this error, I assume that you have specified a datadir in my.cnf. If you are using a non-default data directory for MySQL, you need to move folders mysql and performance_schema (whichever exists) to the data directory specified in my.cnf. You can find these folders in mysql directory.

In MySQL 5.5+ the --skip-locking option is removed. Use --skip-external-locking instead. Refer to MySQL documentation --> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-nutshell.html 
Quote: "The --enable-locking and --skip-locking server options (use --external-locking and --skip-external-locking)."

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl..

1. Navigate to the problem's parent directory `cd YOURPATH/usr/local/mysql`
2. `rm -rf *.local.err` (deletes file)
3. `touch YOURUSERNAME.local.pid` (generates new *.local.pid file the error thrown was complaining about)
4. cd back into your project and restart mysql using `mysql.server start`

Answer (score 0):

Only removing **mysql-bin.index** file in /usr/local/var/mysql/ helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many hours, But this works for me,
Simply change the ownership of the MySQL directory file to the user called 'mysql'.

```
chown -R mysql <path>/mysql-5.7.39-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64
```