# XAMPP - Mysql stopped working on OS X Yosemite (10.10)

Tags: xampp, upgrade, osx-yosemite

I Installed XAMPP 1.8.3-1 on OS X Maverick and all was well, until I upgraded to Yosemite last night, Now when I try to start MySQL in the manager it won't start.

Activity monitor shows no other MySQL processes running. While in the error log I find this message:

> 2014-08-06 17:19:04 5277 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with
>   databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
>       dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_intarray_bind
>         Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
>         Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
>        in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
>       2014-08-06 17:19:05 5277 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This](https://community.bitnami.com/t/mysqld-doesnt-start-in-mac-os-yosemite/25153/6) seems to indicate that you can edit:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp
```

and look for:

```
$XAMPP_ROOT/bin/mysql.server start > /dev/null &
```

and add `unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on top of it. It should look like:

```
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
$XAMPP_ROOT/bin/mysql.server start > /dev/null &
```

It seems you could also edit:

```
/Applications/mampstack-version/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh
```

and add the `unset` to the top of that file as well:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```