# XAMPP 1.8.3-5 OSX 10.10.1 Yosemite MySQL does not start

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, osx-yosemite

There are a few other documented versions of this issue, but they are all related to the older versions of XAMPP that suggest adding unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to the startup manager, this is already added in 1.8.3-5, Another suggests starting mysql from the terminal, which gives me an error.

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start 

Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/stn04.local.pid).
```

There are no other versions of MySQL running in activity monitor.

Comment: Did you recently change permissions to the XAMPP/xamppfiles folder? Create backups of your existing DBs and reinstall everything

Comment: @carlosh12 Backed up, Uninstalled, reinstalled, No dice, Still does not start.

Comment: You're not the only one: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954230/mysql-does-not-start-in-osx-yosemite-10-10), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464439/xampp-mysql-stopped-working-on-os-x-yosemite-10-10), [link3](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=239631&sid=0b4e8f46fe7b432673ea1678e276c2aa)