# MySQL server start issues on Mavericks

Tags: mysql, macos

I am having difficulty using MySQL on my MacBook, I am trying to start my server using `sudo mysqld_safe` and this results in the following output:

```
140131 00:03:02 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/david-mbp.err'.
140131 00:03:02 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
140131 00:03:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/david-mbp.pid ended
```

I had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610875/mysql-pid-ended-cannot-start-mysql) and it has all the same issues and methods I have tried to resolve my issues. His fix was the upgrade to Lion but I am already on the latest version of Mavericks so this is not a viable solution for me.

I have googled around and reinstalled numerous times but haven't managed to find why I get this issue.

How can I fix this issue?

Edit:

```
140131 00:03:02 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2014-01-31 00:03:03 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.15/bin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Binlog end
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-01-31 00:03:03 13223 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.15/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140131 00:03:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/david-mbp.pid ended
```

ls -l /usr/local/var/mysql output:

```
-rw-rw----   1 dave      admin  50331648 30 Jan 22:35 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----   1 dave      admin  50331648 30 Jan 22:35 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw----   1 dave      admin  12582912 30 Jan 22:35 ibdata1
drwx------  81 dave      admin      2754 30 Jan 22:35 mysql
drwx------  55 dave      admin      1870 30 Jan 22:35 performance_schema
-rw-r-----   1 _mysql    admin      4784 31 Jan 00:03 david-mbp.err
drwx------   2 dave      admin        68 30 Jan 22:35 test
```

Comment: Please post the contents (or the most recent, relevant portion) of the error log: `cat /usr/local/var/mysql/david-mbp.err` or `sudo cat /usr/local/var/mysql/david-mbp.err`

Comment: @ATP_JD Sorry for the late reply, was asleep please look at the edit.

Comment: This is indicative of a permissions error. Either the data directory is not owned by MySQL, or mysqld is not being launched as the mysql user. Next piece of info to provide is `ls -l /usr/local/var/mysql/` to see who owns the data directory.

Comment: @ATP_JD Have added the output. Dave being me here.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

File permissions are definitely the cause of the issue. There are far better experts than me, but I recommend the following:

Ensure your entire data directory is owned by the `_mysql` user with permissions `drwxr-xr-x`.

In your case, it appears that your MySQL installation directory is your data directory. My data directory is in a subdirectory of the installation directory.

You can probably get up and running by changing permissions per the command:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:admin /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo chmod -R u+rwX,g+rwX,o-rwx /usr/local/var/mysql
```

This may limit your `dave` account from accessing the mysql installation directory without `sudo`, so you may wish to tweak these permissions to include `g+rwx` if your `dave` user is a member of the `admin` group, which it appears to be. That tweak would be accomplished with:

```
sudo chmod -R g+rwx /usr/local/var/mysql
```

Comment: Ah thanks that worked, but can I ask will I be able to fully delete everything and then try this again? As my installation of MySQL is really buggy.

Comment: Yes, you can. Either with `sudo` or without (if you did the second set of commands to provide access to the group). I agree that your installation layout is not ideal. A re-install from the Mac OS X package would clean a lot of this up.

Comment: This worked for me too.  But I had an unused install at that /usr/local/var/mysql.  Figured out the instance my system has been starting was different (usr/local/mysql).  Otherwise though, this command solved my issue.

Comment: A note for others: My original error message was "MySQL server PID file could not be found!"

Comment: Thanks. Saved my day. Can you tell me the difference between the o and g again?

Answer (score 2):

i fixed that by simply delete the ".err" file. 
Somehow the error log owned by "_mysql" and prevent mysqld zu start.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @LukePeterson it looks to me that this could be a possible fix for the question, no?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a similar problem on Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite. For some reason when I killed the mysql process manually it changed the ownership of the error log file `/usr/local/var/mysql/rally.local.err` to `_mysql` instead of `caleb`. Unlike the accepted solution above, the whole rest of my directory is owned by `caleb`, not `_mysql`.

I fixed it by running `sudo chown caleb /usr/local/var/mysql/rally.local.err`

For the record I guess the proper way to stop and start the mysql server in Yosemite is with `/usr/local/var/mysql/mysql.server start|stop|restart`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any important data, the easiest would be to reinstall MariaDB from scratch (otherwise skip this step), e.g.

```
mv /usr/local/var/mysql /usr/local/var/mysql.bak
brew reinstall mariadb
```

Then fix the permissions by:

```
sudo chmod -R u+rwX,g+rwX,o-rwx /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo chown -R $USER:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
```

Restart MariaDB services by:

```
brew services restart mariadb
```

Consider configuring your MariaDB credentials by running:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

---

### Troubleshooting

- In case it still doesn't work, check the logs for any further issues by:

  ```
  tail /usr/local/var/mysql/*.err
  ```
- For example check if in old config file consist any invalid settings, as they may be not supported anymore.