# MySQL not launching: /data/user.local.err: Permission denied

Tags: mysql, macos

I have just installed MySQL on macOS 10.6, and it will not launch.
When I launch it the traditional way, I get the following:

```
Starting MySQL........
```

> ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
> (/usr/local/mysql/data/user.local.pid).

I followed some other instructions online and deleted my custom my.cnf
file and executed this command:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/mysql/
```

Then tried to launch it in safe mode, to which I received the following list of errors:

```
160414 12:48:18 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/user.local.err'.
touch: /usr/local/mysql/data/user.local.err: Permission denied
160414 12:48:18 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 129: /usr/local/mysql/data/user.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 166: /usr/local/mysql/data/user.local.err: Permission denied
160414 12:48:18 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/user.local.pid ended
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 129: /usr/local/mysql/data/user.local.err: Permission denied
```

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 7):

I know its late, thought helpful for someone in future.

This question already have the answer here:
[MySQL server start issues on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470193/mysql-server-start-issues-on-mavericks).

The following answer is referenced from the above question

Reason:

Probably the folder `/usr/local/mysql/` don't have the write permissions for the user `_mysql`

Try changing the folder permission by using the following commands

`sudo chown -R _mysql:admin /usr/local/mysql`

`sudo chmod -R u+rwX,g+rwX,o-rwx /usr/local/mysql`

Comment: With Catalina 14.10 I also needed to run these commands on `/usr/local/mysql-8.x.x...` directory for anything to take effect

Comment: I did these in Catalina to no avail

Comment: @ChrisF Solved a problem?

Comment: I did these on Big Sur and the problem still persists. I also did the commands on my mysql.x.x.x version and still the problem persists.