# MySQL Error, I've tried everything I could

Tags: mysql, macos

My MySQl server was working fine yesterday, but then all the sudden this morning I've been getting this error:

```
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
[Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.15-osx10.6-x86/data/Xero.lower-test
[Warning] Can't create test file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.15-osx10.6-x86/data/Xero.lower-test
[Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
[Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
[Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
[Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
[ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
```

when I try `mysqld`

I've tried:

Reinstalling

[can't start MySql in Mac OS 10.6 Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334272/cant-start-mysql-in-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard)

(since I noticed `[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB`
)

http://www.debian-tutorials.com/how-to-fix-error-unknownunsupported-storage-engine-innodb

Comment: Please post a comment regarding why you would downvote my post.

Comment: Please post a comment regarding why you would post this question on Stack Overflow and not Server Fault.

Comment: Then why do I see other posts with MySQL errors in stackoverflow with upvotes?

Comment: Just like the answer I posted in my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334272/cant-start-mysql-in-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard

Comment: Because those questions are four years old.

Comment: Check whether there is another mysqld is running so that it cannot open idbdata1.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
[ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
```

It sounds like this file (among others) is not writable by the user that `mysqld` is running as. Check your file permissions.

It's also possible that the file has been deleted.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to run it with a .bat file, just right click on the file and then "run as Administrator".
I had the same problem and that fixed id for me.

Comment: It's OSX not Windows